# Trying to build a DLL from Microsoft PICT repository

Tags: c#, c++, cmake, dll

I'm trying to build a dll for the microsoft PICT model:

https://github.com/microsoft/pict

My objective is to be able to call the model API from another code project.

I modified the makefile in order to produce a dll on windows instead of a so
Here are the changes:

1. Added `TARGET_LIB_DLL=libpict.dll` as an environment variable
2. Added the following target

> ```
> $(TARGET_LIB_DLL): $(OBJS)
>     $(CXX) -fPIC -shared -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET_LIB_DLL)
> ```

Running `make libpict.dll` did generate a dll.

I've been trying to validate this dll using dependency walker and it returns me the following: **Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.**

There are many missing dlls and they all seems to belong to `API-MS-WIN.*`, `AZUREATTESTMANAGER`, `WPAXHOLDER` and `EXT-MS-ONECORE.*`

I am quite rusted with Cpp as I haven't touched it in decades, would you have any idea how I could solve this, maybe I also need to modify the code in the Microsoft repository to make sure I export the methods I want to use, they are located in [picapi.h](https://github.com/microsoft/pict/blob/main/api/pictapi.h) but I don't see any export there.

Also, I could use the executable directly (I can build it and it works), but I need to be able to access the API methods directly via the code, and not via the command line.

I will take any advice that will help me achieve that :) thanks

Comment: Following your link the is a description on how to build for windows. Why not simply follow that guide?

Comment: You should built it with Visual Studio on Windows, I'm guessing you're attempting to use MinGW or similar

Comment: I'm currently automating the process and need a dll, not an executable. Plus the msbuild is deficient due to Visual Studio Tool being unable to properly setup itself. Even if I had asked out of simple curiosity or educational purposes, I'd appreciate having an answer to my question instead of workaround I will not use.